# Install NPM modules on current project while offline

Tags: npm, node-modules, create-react-app

this question might seem stupid but I'm looking for a solution to this scenario:
Let's say I'm starting a new project at an offline environment and I have some npm packages installed globally on my laptop and I'd like to use them for a new project I just created.
For example: I've used npm i -g create-react-app and now I'd like to use create-react-app to make a new react app but I'm currently offline.

I've tried to follow an "offline npm" solution where I basically create an npm server on my computer but I didn't manage to make it work, and am not sure if this will give me the solution I'm looking for.

Sorry if this was answered before, I couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try run

```
create-react-app youproject
```

when you are offline. For me, this sometimes work, sometimes not.

Other solution is install offline all packages, defined in package.json file. You can do this, if you have this packages installed in online mode.

So you can try install this packages, using:

```
npm link packagename
```

or

```
npm i './path_to_package_in_user_directory' // yes, you can also install packages from folder
```

This solution is also ok, when you try add new packages to existing project. Sometimes this causes error and you need reinstall all packages (that's big pain), but most of all, works good.